# boolean not working correctly

Tags: python, tkinter, boolean

I'm trying to get the following code to create 2 buttons which when you press one button will show the fader and when the other button is pressed will hide the fader, but obviously this isn't working i think this is mainly because i can't get my head around how booleans work in python so if somebody could help me i would greatly appreciate it.

```
from tkinter import *

#first window   
master= Tk()
master.geometry('1440x900+0+0')    
master.title('DMX512 Controller')



#buttons
bw=250
bh=110

bool1show = False



Button(master,text="show the slider", command =bool1show= True).place(x=800,y=10)
Button(master,text="hide the slider", command = bool1show= not True).place(x=900,y=10)




#slider characteristics
slw=130
sll=600
sly=1
stc='blue'


if bool1show==True:
    Scale(master, from_=255, to=0, length =sll,width =slw, troughcolor = stc).grid(row=sly,column=5)
if bool1show==not True:
    Scale(from_=255, to=0, length =sll,width =slw, troughcolor = stc).grid(row=sly,column=5)
```

Comment: `if bool1show==not True` is not valid. Try `if not bool1show == True` or just `if not bool1show:`

Comment: @karthikr: it's perfectly valid; `not True` is `False`, so you're just comparing `bool1show` to `False`, which is a valid (yet awkward) way to write `if not bool1show` (assuming `bool1show` is a boolean value).

Comment: @nooodl Try it out in a python console (atleast 2.x). `bool1show==not True` is not valid

Comment: Yeah, you need parentheses around `not True`. Logically it's valid, though.

Comment: Is this your whole code? I thought tkinter applications need a `mainloop` call. BTW, any code occurring before `mainloop` will execute so fast, the user can't possibly click on any controls before then. So `bool1show` will definitely be false by the time it reaches your conditionals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give a reference to a function in the `command` parameter, and `bool1show= True` is not a reference to a function. However, since all you're doing is showing or hiding a widget, you don't need to use a boolean variable at all unless you're using radiobuttons (which you're not).

For the code you've posted, you just need two functions: one to show the slider and one to hide it.  To do that, you create the Scale once, and then use the `grid` methods to show and hide it. To make that work, you have to "remember" the scale widget by saving a reference in a global variable.

```
def show_scale():
    # note: grid will remember the values you used when you first called grid
    the_scale.grid()

def hide_scale():
    # this removes the scale from view, but remembers where it was
    the_scale.grid_remove()

the_scale = Scale(master, from_=255, to=0, length =sll,width =slw, troughcolor = stc)
the_scale.grid(row=sly, column=5)
...
Button(master,text="show the slider", command show_scale).place(x=800,y=10)
Button(master,text="hide the slider", command hide_scale).place(x=900,y=10)
```

On an unrelated note, I strongly encourage you to *not* use place. Your GUIs will be easier to write and maintain, and they will behave better when being resized or run on systems with different resolutions or different fonts.

Comment: Thanks that's perfect and makes far more sense than the way i was trying to do it! i didn't know about the grid_remove commands!!! thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

There is some ambiguity in your code so ii'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. If you want to verify a True condition you can do:

```
if bool1show == True:
  do stuff...
#or
if bool1show:
  do stuff...
```

if bool1show==not True: does not work. If you really want to go like this you can do:

```
if bool1show==(not True)
#or better:
if bool1show == False
#even better:
if not bool1show:
```

Hope this helps understand better python booleans

Comment: Im basically trying to say,bool1show starts off false, if this button is pressed turn bool1show true if the other button is pressed turn boolshow1 false, if bool1show equals true....show the slider, if bool1show equals false don't show the slider...............would you be able to give me an example of how i can make this work? Thanks

Comment: `command=True` won't do what you think it does (unless you think it does nothing...).

Comment: @ BryanOakley - Yes, you are right. I was not familiar with the tinkter library, but after reading some documentation I understand that command should be a method or function. I edited out that part. Thanks

Comment: @user2996828 Maybe you should reformulate your question then. My answer was related to how booleans in python work. To answer your new question I would need to be familiar with the tkinter package and I am not...

Answer (score 0):

How about if you assign the `command` argument to a lambda function that calls another function:

```
Button(master,text="show the slider", command=lambda: bool_func(bool1show).place(x=800,y=10)
Button(master,text="hide the slider",command=lambda: bool_func(bool1show,b=False).place(x=900,y=10)
```

where:

```
def bool_func(variable, b=True): # b is True by default, hence you don't provide the argument in the first Button statement.
    variable = b
    return variable
```

for some info on lambda functions, look [here](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/lambda_functions.html)